# What does Trans # refer to in Custom Transaction Detail Report

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

When I run Custom Transaction Detail Report in QuickBooks, I can include a column called Trans #. I am not sure what it means. How is it different from Reference Number and Transaction ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trans # and Transaction ID are both internal unique ID's of the transaction that are automatically generated by QuickBooks. Neither of them are something that you can edit or even see when you have the transaction itself open. I'm not sure why QuickBooks has both, other than that I don't think you can see the Transaction ID via the GUI.

Reference number is a user defined ID for the transaction (check number, "Entry No." on Journal Entries, etc.). This can be edited after the fact and doesn't have to be unique.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That means I can use Transaction Number to determine which items belong to the same transaction which is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: @BenStrombeck, do you know how to determine the transaction ID of, say, a purchase order in QB? I'm needing the ID for an import.

Comment: You can get it programmatically via the QB SDK. I prefer to use RSSBus ADO.NET provider instead of directly using the SDK. It's got great documentation that would be able to tell you how to do this as well - see http://cdn.rssbus.com/help/RQ4/ado/pg_desktoptable-purchaseorders.htm